# After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, KDE programs don't work any more

Tags: 13.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 i cannot run any more KDE programs under Ubuntu.
I have both installed. Ubuntu and Kubuntu.
I run Rkonq and K3B already lots of years under Ubuntu.
But after the upgrade it is not possible any more.
This is what i get starting Rekonq from a terminal:
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
unnamed app(3756) kdemain: rekonq is already running!

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. I just opened Synaptic Package Manager and installed the k3b packages(version 2.0.2-6ubuntu1). Results: k3b works.

Answer (score 1):

I just got around to upgrading my work ubuntu machine, KDE environment would not run but it did complain about starting dbus.  CTRL+ALT+F1 (or any console).

```
sudo apt-get install qdbus
```

The update uninstalled the 386 version and installed a new version.  ALT+F7, login with KDE came up just fine after this.

Answer (score -1):

I installed `ubuntu-sdk` as described here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130894&p=12581777#post12581777

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.